# What do the at-signs in Rundeck's @option.message@ example mean to bash?

Tags: bash, rundeck

The [Rundeck docs](http://rundeck.org/1.6.2/manual/job-options.html#script-usage) give the example of defining a `message` option (parameter) which can then be referred to by the script in a number of ways, including

`echo message=@option.message@  ;# replacement token`

We use this syntax and it seems fine, but I have no idea what those two `@`s actually *mean* to bash; I can't find mention of anything beyond `$@`, or anything relevant for the "replacement token" in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://rundeck.org/1.6.2/manual/job-options.html#script-usage) you linked, that is a "replacement token" handled by Rundeck.  That is, Rundeck replaces the `@...@` before passing the command to bash.  Consequently, they don't mean anything to bash :) .  Specifically, the docs say:

> Inline Script workflow steps that contain a token expansion will be expanded into a temporary file, and the temp file will contain the plaintext option value.

So bash sees the temp file post-expansion, *without* the `@...@` sequences and *with* their values as literal text.

The docs also note that "If the option is blank or unset the token will be replaced with a blank string."  Therefore, the whole `@...@` sequence will disappear if a particular token is not defined.

See also [this section on script usage](http://rundeck.org/1.6.2/manual/job-options.html#script-usage) and [this section on context variables](http://rundeck.org/1.6.2/manual/job-workflows.html#context-variables) in the docs.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'd seen the first bit you quote, but the context made it look specific to secure options. The context variables docs were what I was looking for.